# How to get model property name in a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core partial view that solicits (for example) a person's first and last name. The partial view takes this view model:

```
// MyApp.NamePartialViewModel.cs
public class NamePartialViewModel{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The partial view renders input elements for its view model, like this (obviously, I've omitted labels and unobtrusive validation stuff):

```
@* NamePartialView.cshtml *@
@model MyApp.NamePartialViewModel
<input asp-for="FirstName" />
<input asp-for="LastName>" />
```

Now, the partial view is referenced in a parent view. For the sake of a reasonably complete example, I'll use the partial view to get names for two different people, so the view model looks like this:

```
// MyApp.MyViewModel.cs
public class MyViewModel {
  public NamePartialViewModel FirstPersonName { get; set; }
  public NamePartialViewModel SecondPersonName { get; set; }
}
```

And, finally, the parent view (displayed by the controller) looks like this:

```
@model MyApp.MyViewModel
<form method="post">
  <partial name="NamePartialView" model="@Model.FirstPersonName" />
  <partial name="NamePartialView" model="@Model.SecondPersonName" />
</form>
```

The point here is that each `<partial>` element feeds an instance of `NamePartialViewModel` to the partial view.

My question is: **Is there a way, in the partial view (or in code called from the partial view) to get the name of the property bound to the Model?** In other words, I want to discover that (in this example) my model is bound to a property named either FirstPersonName or SecondPersonName (that is, the name of the property in the parent view model).

So, why do I need this, you ask? Because in order for the model binding in the controller POST routine to work correctly, I need to prefix the `<input>` element's `name` attribute with the property name, so the first partial view invocation would actually render something like this:

```
<input name="FirstPersonName.FirstName" id="FirstPersonName_FirstName" />
<input name="FirstPersonName.LastName" id="FirstPersonName_LastName" />
```

so I need some code that can fabricate the prefix based on **the name of the property in the parent view model** that becomes the view model for the partial view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `partial` tag helper when you pass a model using `for`, the property name will be accessible through [`ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.templateinfo.htmlfieldprefix?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the partial view.

As long as you use standard helpers you don't need to use `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`, however as an author of a tag helper or as the one who wants to use manual tag renderings, you need to care about it.

*NamePartialView.cshtml*

```
@model MyApp.NamePartialViewModel

<label asp-for="FirstName" />
<input asp-for="FirstName" />
<label asp-for="LastName" />
<input asp-for="LastName" />

Just in case of creating manual tags, here is the prefix to use:
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

*MyViewModel.cshtml*

```
@model MyApp.MyViewModel

<partial name="NamePartialView" for="FirstPersonName" />
<partial name="NamePartialView" for="SecondPersonName" />
```